# Running Maven and Sonatype Nexus while offline with no internet connection

Tags: maven, configuration, build, nexus

I am trying to setup a maven environment with nexus so that maven downloads its artifacts from a local Nexus repository. The machine where Maven and Nexus is installed has no internet connectivity for security reasons.

I have a similar configuration on my workstation which does have internet connectivity. I installed Maven and Nexus on both machines. I also updated my local maven settings file in  ~m2/settings.xml as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies></proxies>
  <servers></servers>
  <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I have run to run a simple "mvn install" on the secure server and it complained about missing dependencies. This is expected because i have not downloaded and uploaded any artifacts onto the repository.

I would like to download the artifacts using my local workstation, zip them up and then upload them on to the Nexus repository on the secure machine. I have run 'mvn install' on my local workstation and everything has been downloaded. Now i need to copy the repository on the local workstation to the secure server.

According to the Nexus documentation, the folder `$HOME/sonatype-work` is the "storage" location.

- Is this folder the only folder i need to copy to the secure server in order to copy the repository?
- Are there any other files i need to worry about? e.g. configuration files?
- I noticed that by default, Nexus disables the remote repositories. Does this mean that if i leave it as it is i dont need to do anything to prevent it to download anything from the central repository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to upload the contents of your local repository to the Nexus server's storage area. You might need to re-index or regenerate the repositories metadata (tasks that can be invoked via the Nexus GUI).

However.... I would recommend that you consider an alternative solution that will ultimately result in less maintenance.

The Professional edition of Nexus has [procurement suite](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/procure.html) feature that enables you to create repositories whose content is controlled by rules or based on a reference build.

Open up the firewall so that only Nexus has access to the internet. enables you to give development controlled access to any 3rd party Nexus repository.

Comment: Hi Mark, the option of enabling the firewall is practically impossible due to the secure nature of the project. Thanks.

Comment: The following question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997219/disable-maven-central-repository/4997553#4997553