# mvn cannot download a jar issue

Tags: maven

when I build a project in linux environment, it says:

`[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1` or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.0-beta-1:` Could not transfer artifact `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.0-beta-1` from/to Main `Maven Repo` `(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): repo1.maven.org:` Unknown host repo1.maven.org -> [Help 1]

I'm using my company internal mirror repository.

Any one help me?

Update:
I copied the .m2 folder to the `linux home/user_name` , resolved this issue

Comment: Are you behind the proxy?

Comment: Are you sure you are using your internal mirror? `Unknown host repo1.maven.org`

Comment: How is your internal mirror configured? And are you able to download other artifacts without problems? Try for instance to change version on one of the plugins you are using and see if you can download that particular version.

Comment: I reset the setting.xml  using the internal repository, the maven should search under it, I also don't understand why it search under the repo1.maven.org

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only your company's repo and not the public ones, such as maven central, take a look here [Disable Maven central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997219/disable-maven-central-repository).

Otherwise you need your station/network configured to allow access to the public repos and resolve their IPs from the hostnames.

Comment: My linux cannot access the network so I config the internal repository, the repository can access the network.

Comment: Then you need to set up your internal repo to mirror the central, as it is described in the accepted answer for the linked question.

Comment: you can check your config by doing `mvn help:effective-pom`.  Looking at the result you can tell if you configured your maven project correctly to use the internal repo.