# is it possible to tell dependabot to not connect to central maven at all

Tags: maven, github, dependabot, dependabot-script

In enterprise environment, the connection to central maven could be blocked. In this case,
i) either don't connect to central maven at all
ii) or if the connection to central maven is not successful, don't raise exception, just move on to other repositories

currently i see below exception

```
/vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/excon-0.76.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:285:in `select_with_timeout': connect_write timeout reached (Excon::Error::Timeout)
```

so I am wondering if there is any way to tell dependabot to not try connecting to maven central at all.

fyi. i am running https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-script

Comment: Don't you have a repository manager running?

Comment: yes we do have nexus running on internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what happens in an enterprise environment, it does have the local repository like Nexus within the network. Now you mirror your local nexus repo in settings.xml. You can mirror any no. of  repo in your settings.xml. Now, maven first try to find the dependencies in your all local repo first and if it does not find it, only then it goes for maven central repo.
If the maven central is not block, then the library first downloaded to your local nexus repo and then would be downloaded to your local. So next time when you will try to download this library, it will be available in your local enterprise nesus repo.
You can block the maven central repo, refer -  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997219/disable-maven-central-repository#:~:text=In%20maven's%20home%2C%20in%20the,or%20just%20override%20it's%20definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997219/disable-maven-central-repository#:%7E:text=In%20maven%27s%20home%2C%20in%20the,or%20just%20override%20it%27s%20definition).
But as per your question, if the dependency library not found in any repo, there would always be an exception in maven build.

Comment: agree thats how maven works. but my problem is how dependabot works. it looks like dependabot first looks up in  central maven before local nexus.

Comment: I don't have much idea about dependabot, but i have found https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/503 may be it can help a bit and may have something what you are looking for.