# How can I configure GITLAB CI with NEXUS?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nexus

I want to create a pipeline with Gitlab CI to compile a maven project.

First, I create a `.m2` folder in root of my project and I add the `settings.xml` config file.
My project look like :

```
Project
 - module1
 - module2
 - module3
 - pom.xml
 - .m2
     -setting.xml
```

In the settings file I do this :

```
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nichefactory-releases</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>nichefactory-snapshots</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
                <flex.debug>true</flex.debug>
            </properties>

            <repositories>
                <repository> 
                    <id>nichefactory</id>
                    <name>NicheFactory Repository</name>
                    <url>http://my-nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

In my `pom.xml` I have this repository :

```
<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Publish the versioned releases to nexus -->
    <repository>
        <id>nichefactory-releases</id>
        <name>Niche Factory Repository (RELEASE)</name>
        <url>http://my-nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Publish the snapshot release to nexus -->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nichefactory-snapshots</id>
        <name>Niche Factory Repository (SNAPSHOTS)</name>
        <url>http://my-nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have :

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - mvn compile -P dev -DskipTests
```

When I push this config to gitlab, the pipeline start  with a failure message :

```
Failure to find apps:pom:version in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10
```

It seems that gitlab try to connect to the default maven repository and not to my nexus.

How can I tell gitlab to call the nexus repository and not the default repository ?

Comment: You could [disable the default repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999921/10871900)

Comment: I add this config in my pom.xml , but it dosen't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAVEN_CLI_OPTS` is not an official MAVEN environment variable, but the recommended way to store repeating options. you can even see this in the [GitLab Example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml#L52)

Just try:

```yaml
build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile -P dev -DskipTests
```