# Drools KieScanner is looking at Maven central and nexus repositories for dependency and artifacts. how to configure this to pick up from filesystem

Tags: spring-boot, drools

During application scaling we are seeing delay in starting pods for one of our Spring boot drools project.
As we find that KieScanner is looking for artifacts and dependencies from Nexus and Maven Central,
which is causing random delay of 15-30 seconds delay in startup.
Is there any way to configure this to pick up artifacts and dependencies from local filesystem only.

KieScanner should only look at local m2 path and not at remote repositories

Answer (score 2):

KieScanner uses Maven, which in turn is configured per standard Maven settings. If you want to disable a lookup to Maven central, ensure you have setup you local Nexus to be the mirror in your Maven settings file used by your Drools SB application.

See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Additionally in the Maven settings used by your Spring Boot application, you might want to disable `central` like explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999921/893991).

If nothing solves, provide a reproducer (a simple example Drools app similar to yours) with instruction to replicate the issue to let the Drools community better support on your question.